# XElement attribute group by

Tags: c#, grouping, xelement

I've got xml

```
<Customer>
  <Vendor Value="Vodafone">
    <CustomerBarcode>10010</CustomerBarcode>
    <Description>Vodafone CepLira 10 TL</Description>
    <UnitAmount>0</UnitAmount>
  </Vendor>
  <Vendor Value="Vodafone">
    <CustomerBarcode>10020</CustomerBarcode>
    <Description>Vodafone CepLira 20 TL</Description>
    <UnitAmount>0</UnitAmount>
  </Vendor>
  <Vendor Value="Vodafone">
    <CustomerBarcode>10030</CustomerBarcode>
    <Description>Vodafone CepLira 30 TL</Description>
    <UnitAmount>0</UnitAmount>
  </Vendor>
  <Vendor Value="Vodafone">
    <CustomerBarcode>10050</CustomerBarcode>
    <Description>Vodafone CepLira 50 TL</Description>
    <UnitAmount>0</UnitAmount>
  </Vendor>
  <Vendor Value="Vodafone">
    <CustomerBarcode>10100</CustomerBarcode>
    <Description>Vodafone CepLira 100 TL</Description>
    <UnitAmount>0</UnitAmount>
  </Vendor>
</Customer>
```

```
 var xml = new XElement("Customer",
                from prod in _customer
                group prod by new { prod.Vendor, prod.CustomerBarcode, prod.Description, prod.UnitAmount } into g
                select new XElement("Vendor",new XAttribute("Value",g.Key.Vendor),
                    new XElement("CustomerBarcode", g.Key.CustomerBarcode),
                     new XElement("Description", g.Key.Description),
                     new XElement("UnitAmount", g.Key.UnitAmount)
              ));
```

I want to group by Vendor Value like this:

```
  <Customer>
  <Vendor Value="Vodafone">
    <CustomerBarcode>10010</CustomerBarcode>
    <Description>Vodafone CepLira 10 TL</Description>
    <UnitAmount>0</UnitAmount>
    <CustomerBarcode>10020</CustomerBarcode>
    <Description>Vodafone CepLira 20 TL</Description>
    <UnitAmount>0</UnitAmount>
     <CustomerBarcode>10020</CustomerBarcode>
    <Description>Vodafone CepLira 20 TL</Description>
    <UnitAmount>0</UnitAmount>
     <CustomerBarcode>10030</CustomerBarcode>
    <Description>Vodafone CepLira 30 TL</Description>
    <UnitAmount>0</UnitAmount>
     <CustomerBarcode>10050</CustomerBarcode>
    <Description>Vodafone CepLira 50 TL</Description>
    <UnitAmount>0</UnitAmount>
     <CustomerBarcode>10100</CustomerBarcode>
    <Description>Vodafone CepLira 100 TL</Description>
    <UnitAmount>0</UnitAmount> 
  </Vendor>
</Customer>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You should define grouping key: in your case it would be `Vender` property value itself, not all properties.

And your should use `SelectMany` to get all group items into one big collection.

Following should do the trick:

```
var xml = new XElement("Customer",
                from prod in _customer
                group prod by prod.Vendor into g
                let vendor = g.Key
                let items = g.SelectMany(x => x)
                select
                    new XElement("Vendor",
                        new XAttribute("Value",g.Key.Vendor),
                        items.SelectMany(i => 
                            new XElement[] {
                                 new XElement("CustomerBarcode", i.CustomerBarcode),
                                 new XElement("Description", i.Description),
                                 new XElement("UnitAmount", i.UnitAmount)
                            }
                        )
                    )
                );
```

But, just to make it clear: I think that's XML structure is not really a good choice. You should group units together, probably use something like:

```
<Customer>
  <Vendor Value="Vodafone">
    <Unit>
      <CustomerBarcode>10010</CustomerBarcode>
      <Description>Vodafone CepLira 10 TL</Description>
      <UnitAmount>0</UnitAmount>
    </Unit>
    <Unit>
      <CustomerBarcode>10020</CustomerBarcode>
      <Description>Vodafone CepLira 20 TL</Description>
      <UnitAmount>0</UnitAmount>
    </Unit>
    <Unit>
      <CustomerBarcode>10020</CustomerBarcode>
      <Description>Vodafone CepLira 20 TL</Description>
      <UnitAmount>0</UnitAmount>
    </Unit>
    <Unit>
      <CustomerBarcode>10030</CustomerBarcode>
      <Description>Vodafone CepLira 30 TL</Description>
      <UnitAmount>0</UnitAmount>
    </Unit>
    <Unit>
      <CustomerBarcode>10050</CustomerBarcode>
      <Description>Vodafone CepLira 50 TL</Description>
      <UnitAmount>0</UnitAmount>
    </Unit>
    <Unit>
      <CustomerBarcode>10100</CustomerBarcode>
      <Description>Vodafone CepLira 100 TL</Description>
      <UnitAmount>0</UnitAmount>
    </Unit>
  </Vendor>
</Customer>
```

It makes the document much more readable. To achieve that, use following LINQ query:

```
var xml = new XElement("Customer",
                from prod in _customer
                group prod by prod.Vendor into g
                let vendor = g.Key
                let items = g.SelectMany(x => x)
                select
                    new XElement("Vendor",
                        new XAttribute("Value",g.Key.Vendor),
                        items.Select(i => 
                            new XElement("Unit",
                                 new XElement("CustomerBarcode", i.CustomerBarcode),
                                 new XElement("Description", i.Description),
                                 new XElement("UnitAmount", i.UnitAmount)
                            )
                        )
                    )
                );
```